# Why  this Symfony2 routing is not working?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with the routing in Symfony2.

Actually I downloaded the latest release and run it on my server. The demo works fine.

Now I want to do the following:
I want to create a TestController, this controller should have:

- an index view
- a view like hello world
- a view where i can pass 2 parameters

So I started to create a new controller in the `src\Acme\DemoBundle\Controller` folder called `TestController`. Here is the code:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Acme\DemoBundle\Form\ContactType;

// these import the "@Route" and "@Template" annotations
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array();
    }

    public function hello2Action($name1, $name2)
    {
        return array();
    }

    public function helloAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Then I created 3 views in a new folder `src\Acme\DemoBundle\Resources\views\Test` called `hello.html.twig`, `index.html.twig` and `hello2.html.twig`

Both of them have a content like this

```
{% extends "AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title "Symfony - Demos" %}

{% block content_header '' %}

{% block content %}
    foo!!!
{% endblock %}
```

Finally I edited the `routing.dev.yml` and added somthing like this:

```
_name1:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/TestController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /test

_name2:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/TestController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /test/hello

_name3:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/TestController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /test/hello2/{name1}&{name2}
```

When i want to run the test controller i get:

> No route found for "GET /test/"

What is wrong?
Is it possible to have one view for two controller functions? (like hello() and hello($foo))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this:

1. In routing_dev.yml, make sure you have this:

   ```
    _main:
        resource: routing.yml
   ```
2. In routing.yml, add something like this:

   ```
      AcmeDemoBundle:
         resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
         prefix:   /test
   ```

   You can select the prefix you want in accessing that particular bundle.
3. In Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml you can now add your route patterns.

   ```
     name1:
         pattern: /
         defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Test:index }

     name2:
         pattern: /hello
         defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Test:hello }

     name3:
         pattern: /hello2/{name1}/{name2}
         defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Test:hello2 }
   ```

And you can now access, route **/test**, **/test/hello** and **/test/hello2/firstname/lastname'**. This is just one way of managing routes in symfony 2. This might help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: The controller must return a response (Array() given).

Comment: In every action in your controller, return something like this: $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Test:index.html.twig') if you want to render your template. For more information visit these: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-response-object and http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#rendering-templates.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- You have defined a route for "/test" but not for "/test/", that is why you got your first error message (No route found for "GET /test/"). In any case, it is better to define routes as annotations as suggested in another answer.
- In order for Controllers to work with the structure you are using (returning and array of variables, in this case an empty array), you need to mark them with the "@Template" annotation like so:

> /*
>
> ```
> * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="_demo_hello")
> * @Template()
> */    
> public function helloAction($name)
> ```

This makes Symfony look automatically for the corresponding template files. If you don´t do this, you need to return a Response object, indicating the template that should be rendered, something like this:

```
return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Test:index.html.twig');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your routing you defined prefixes, but not actually the routes. Since you are using annotations - routes must be defined via annotations in the Controller.

See this [great manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html) ;)

Your `routing_dev.yml` should look like this:

```
_name1:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/TestController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

And in your controller you should define @Route for each action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/hello")
 */
public function helloAction()
{
    return array();
}
```

After this you'll be able to access your action by route `/hello` and so on.

Cheers ;)